# Method to read data from local file or remote URL: how to pass arguments?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, arguments, overloading

I am creating a class that de-serializes a XML file and creates some object from it.

The method is more or less like this (C#-style pseudocode):

```
this.Load(string url_or_filename, out string file_content) {
    try { 
        string filename = url_or_filename;
        loadFile(filename, resultstring);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) {
        string url = url_or_filename;          
        loadUrl(url, resultstring);
    }
}
```

The question is: Would it be considered a good practice to pass a "magic string" to this function, and let it handle the intention from the string, thus providing an easy to use interface for users of an API, for example, or is it wiser to have two different methods, one for local filepaths, other for remote URLs?

(this could be asked more broadly as: "should I have a single method that accepts a lot of argument types, or a lot of overloads of a single-named method (not strictly doable in Python, for example), or each method should do a single thing in a single way, and thus I should have more methods, each one with its single name?)

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer my methods/functions do a single thing. In this case I'd consider using a new abstraction: streams.

```
// in the same C#-pseudocode 
string load(Stream source)
{
    return source.ReadAll();
}
```

At the caller site someone will know if it's a file or a http request so you can decide:

```
// reading from file
foo(string filename)
{
    Stream source = new File(filename).getStream();
    load(source);
}

// reading from an url
bar(string url)
{
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(url);
    Stream source = request.getResponseStream();
    load(source);
}
```

If your XML deserialization can read from streams (and chances are it can) you can skip the stream->string reading. It might be important if the content can be large.

Comment: Could you please tell me more about reading to a string and then parsing the string versus parsing the file-object or url instead? When is one of them preferrable? For example, python has `json.load(file_object)` and `json.loads(json_string)` and I'm always in doubt what should be the desired use-case for each one...

Comment: if you read the content into a string before processing it will keep it in memory. This can cause problems if the file/http response is large (think 1GB files).

If you deal with user input (from web forms, user files) you should be prepared for this. You don't want your application to blow up when processing a large file/submission.